# Wordpress 3.3 auto update not working

Tags: automatic-updates

I am at my wit's end! Trying to auto upgrade to Wordpress 3.3 and its not working. I have tried every trick I found on the net

1. The entire wordpress directory and all its sub directories has been given 0777
2. Somewhere I saw a tip about deleting the upgrade directory and trying again, BUT no upgrade directory is ever created.

When I try to upgrade wordpress, I get so far as to WP asking me for FTP info, which I do provide (and it is 100% correct) and then when I hit next nothing happens. I just see a semi blank page with the left hand menus and nothing on the right hand side, the page just keeps loading and loading and loading.

No error log is created, no error mesages are displayed on screen.

I am going to pull out my hair in frustration. Please help.

Comment: Oh and to add ALL the plugins are disabled.

Comment: I waited long enough for WP to actually show me some error and finally it did.

The error I got was 

Unable to locate WordPress Plugin directory.

And [this][1] solution worked for me.

This is about adding a following lines of code to the wp-config file.


    if(is_admin()) {
     add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
     define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
    }

And this worked.


  [1]: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-locate-wordpress-plugin-directory-1?replies=12#post-1329821

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with the auto upgrade, just [download a fresh copy](http://wordpress.org/download/) and drag + drop the folders in your FTP client, make sure you select to "merge" so you don't overwrite your `wp-config.php` or `wp-content` folder (in fact take backups!). Then as soon as you go to the wp-admin WP will prompt you to visit an update page.

It's actually quite tricky to get the permissions perfect for autoupdating, you often get yourself in a situation where you leave your server in a dangerous state (chmod 777 everything) or lock yourself out of editing files (everything owned by server).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions of this WP codex guide to do manual upgrade if your server having issues with the auto upgrade: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on

http://www.ganshani.com/2011/12/20/upgrading-to-wordpress-3-3-on-godaddy-hosting for step-by-step guide to upgrading Wordpress 3.3